# fire event when clicking on any Item in Select (even on selected one)

Tags: sapui5, hana

I have a dropdown Select list with always 1 option(Item) enabled and 1 disabled. I want to `change` event fire every time I click the `Item` but it's not the case when I have for instance `selectedKey=0` set and clicking on the `Item key="0"`. Thus, the question is whether there is some way to fire an event once Item is clicked, or I should look for another control like Toggle,etc.?

```
<Select
    change="onChangeOrderStatusInternal"
    selectedKey="0">
<core:Item enabled="false"
           key="0" text="disabledItem" />
<core:Item enabled="true"
           key="1000" text="enabledItem" />
</Select>
```

Comment: Whats the point? Why would you fire an event when nothing changes?

Comment: @Marc I agree, but our POs wants this behavior :/ therefore asking

Comment: If one item is always disabled then why show it at all? Without knowing the context it seems to me like you need a different UI approach.

Comment: @Marc thanks for the response. will look for smth else. Btw is openui5 supported by community?

Comment: If by community you mean "SAP customers" then yes. They listen to demands and provide new features and are open for pull-requests. But I don't think anyone outside of the SAP world has heard of it.